# I can't not create to repository a git hub

Tags: git, push

remote: Permission to atralice/Curso.Prep.Henry.git denied to jepon26.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/atralice/Curso.Prep.Henry.git/': The requested URL returned error: 40

Comment: If you want to try to change someone else's GitHub repo, you have to fork to your own repo then create a pull request.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably trying to push to a repository that it's not yours and you don't have permission for it.

Github doesn't let you commit directly to other peoples repository. What you can do, is `Fork` the repository and start using the forked repository.
Your repository will look something like this: `https://github.com/YOUR_USER_NAME/Curso.Prep.Henry`.

After you commit and push all the necessary changes to your forked repo, you can open a `Pull Request` to Atralice's repository, and if he approves, you code will be merged with the original code base.

[You can follow this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a_FLqX3vGR4).